# Spring: No default constructor found

Tags: spring

My english isn't perfect or even good but I will try to explain my problem.

I need to write in my application REST client which is using Wiki API to get some necessary data.I have no idea what is wrong with this code.

Here is my client:

```
@Component("wikiService")
public class WikiServiceImpl implements WikiService {

private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(WikiServiceImpl.class);

private String wikiBaseURL = "http://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles={name}&rvprop=content&";

private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public WikiServiceImpl() {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
}

@Autowired
public WikiServiceImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}
// other metods ommited
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/ask")
public class WikiController {

    final Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(WikiController.class);

    @Autowired
    private WikiService wikiService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{query}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAnswer(@PathVariable String query) {
        logger.info("Odebralem zapytanie: " + query);
        String bDate = wikiService.getBirthDate(query);
        logger.info("Znaleziona data: " + bDate);
        return bDate;
    }

    public final WikiService getWikiService() {
        return wikiService;
    }

    public final void setWikiService(WikiService wikiService) {
        this.wikiService = wikiService;
    }
}
```

Here is rest servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller"/>
                <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller"/>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.restful.controller"/>

    <bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
        <property name="mappingLocation" value="classpath:oxm-mapping.xml"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Root context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:META-INF/test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.service.jpa, com.wiki.service" />

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.kr.soft.domain"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> 
                org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Error stack:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wikiService' defined in file [/home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/com/wiki/service/WikiServiceImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.wiki.service.WikiServiceImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.wiki.service.WikiServiceImpl.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.wiki.service.WikiServiceImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.wiki.service.WikiServiceImpl.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 23 more
```

Stack says container can't find default constructor which actually is there.
Application is running on TomCat 7.0 Server.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The servlet application context is of no interest here as the error happens during root web application context initialization...

Comment: move the @AutoWired to the default constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error is impossible with the source code you shared with us, my guess would be that your server contains old class (i.e. the source code we see is not being used).

I suggest to clean the project and also Tomcat installation in your IDE.

On project in Eclipse (if that is your IDE):

```
Menu Project => Clean ...
```

On Tomcat in Eclipse (if that is your IDE):

```
Right click on the server in Servers view => Clean ...
```

Comment: Indeed, was just about to suggest the same.

Comment: Thanks! that helps. :) I cleaned project few times but I did't know I can clean on server. Thanks a lot.